# How to get values against oldest date field in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a select query which take values from multiple tables with date as one of the fields:

```
select e.id,e.date,d.d_id
from emp e, d_source d
 where e.d_id = d.d_id and e.emp_id = 100`
```

For each `emp_id`, there are 2 or more records. I have to select `id` from `emp` table against the oldest date value. There are cases when the date field values are null or date field values are same for all the selected records. In such case I have to select the ID which is associated with a particular `d_id` (say 123) of `d_source` table.

What I have tried so far is

```
`select e.id from emp e 
where e.emp_id = 100 
and e.date=(select min(date) from emp where emp_id = 100)`
```

These are some results of the first select query for 3 different emp_id-

[Select results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjv4l.png)

So,  I need to return only 'id' of the record having oldest date value and if date field values are equal or empty, I need to return 'id' of the record which have d_id as 456

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have shown the same query twice, is that intentional or was the second one supposed to be trying to deal with the duplicate dates? Also, sample data and expected results might be useful. I'm also not clear how you want to deal with null dates - if there is a null and a not null which takes precedence? And where does the 123 value come from? (You're probably looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984191/266304), though there are lots of other examples around; where you put your rules into the ranking function `order by` clause...)

Comment: @Alex Poole, sorry my bad. Updated!

Comment: OK, so what is wrong with that query - is it that it doesn't match anything if the date field is null? Do you actually need the join to `d_source` - it doesn't seem to be doing anything? Again, sample data and results would  be helpful.

Comment: All your examples have different ID; earlier you said that there were multiple rows per ID. And none of them are 100. This is a bit confusing. Is each pair of results you've shown supposed to have the same ID, so there are 3 different IDs overall?

Comment: @Alex Poole, appreciate your effort in looking into my problem. I have different 'id's for same 'emp_id'. I need to select only one 'id' against some condition with 'date'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, based on what I understood.

```
SQL> -- sample data
SQL> with emp (emp_id, id, cdate, d_id) as
  2    (select 100, 11111, date '2010-02-26', 123 from dual union all
  3     select 100, 22222, date '2018-02-26', 456 from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 200, 11122, date '2010-02-26', 123 from dual union all
  6     select 200, 22211, date '2010-02-26', 456 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 300, 11133, null, 123 from dual union all
  9     select 300, 22244, null, 456 from dual
 10    ),
 11  source (d_id) as
 12    (select 123 from dual union all
 13     select 456 from dual
 14    )
 15  -- query that, hopefully, returns result you need
 16  select emp_id, id, cdate, d_id
 17  from (select e.emp_id, e.id, e.cdate, d.d_id,
 18          row_number() over (partition by e.emp_id order by e.cdate, d.d_id desc) rn
 19        from emp e join source d on e.d_id = d.d_id
 20       )
 21  where rn = 1
 22  order by emp_id;

    EMP_ID         ID CDATE            D_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100      11111 26/02/2010        123
       200      22211 26/02/2010        456
       300      22244                   456

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. But this doesn't satisfy my request of selecting 'id' of the record which having d_id as 456. Please refer the image link included in the question. I need to return only 'id' of oldest date field and if date fields are equal or empty, I need to return 'id' of the record which have d_id as 456. TIA

Comment: I saw the image you posted, and I'd say that query I wrote returns result you need. Though, there are 3 separate cases on the image, while I put all of them into the same query. You'd just include a `WHERE e.emp_id = some_value` into my query.

Comment: I did that. I'm looking for some option where I can mention the value of d_id when date values are same or null, not using order by clause for d_id. Probably a CASE WHEN clause?

Comment: I don't know; you should. You never explained *which* D_ID value to take, just that it has to be 456, which is the *largest* in the set.